# In android 13 unable to load library "libmagtsync.so" in android studio target 33

Tags: android, android-studio

*your text*error: can't load library: failed: library "libmagtsync.so" not found
while using the fragment view i' m unable to view the fragment page and there is an error that the library in not found error found in the logcat.